# Preset Color Ramp in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.5, color-ramp

I am trying to make a custom color ramp by using preset color ramp in ArcGIS 10.5. I need to show 19 colors. The default number of colors that can be input in preset color ramp is 13.

Is there any way to increase the number of this default input value?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An underhand trick...from my friend...(*I do agree with gisnside*)

1. **New** > **Multi-part Color Ramp**
2. <kbd>Add</kbd> **Algorithmic Color Ramp**
3. Select this **Algorithmic Color Ramp** and <kbd>Properties</kbd> (or, just double-clicking) to open `Edit Color Ramp`window.
4. Give your first color to both *Color 1* and *Color 2*. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to close the window.
5. Again, <kbd>Add</kbd> **Algorithmic Color Ramp** +  <kbd>Properties</kbd> to give your second color to both *Color 1* and *Color 2*.
6. Repeat the above process 19 times.

Answer (score 1):

In a color ramp, you don't put all the colors you need, but just the breaks. For example : from red to green = 2 colors, maybe 3 if you need yellow colors too. Some colors exists between breaks, often you don't need to put all the colors, jst find the right breaks.

13 breaks of color is a lot, probably more than what you can see apart with your eyes. Don't forget that in a color ramp you are displaying much more colors. Maybe you should have a look at other symbology types.